# Discord.py with Wavelink - I want my bot disconnect when there is nothing left to play? but how

Tags: python, discord.py, audio-player

I want to let my bot disconnect from voice channel when there is nothing left to play. Also all command are wrote in cogs.

I try to use `vc.queue.is_empty()` but it will skip one song like below

A Song - Played and finished

B Song - Not Play

System: Skip B song and disconnect

I expect like below:

A Song - Played and finished

B Song - Not Play

System: Play B Song. After B song has finished, disconnect from voice channel.

````
async def on_wavelink_track_end(self, player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track, reason):         
    with open('Music.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as jfile:
        jdata = json.load(jfile)         
    guild = player.guild         
    vc: player = guild.voice_client         
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(jdata[str(guild.id)]['Older_Channel']))```         

    if self.is_looped == True: #it work              
        await vc.play(track)         
    else:             
        if have_next_song: #here, i do not know what should put in there                 
            await vc.play(next_song)
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Now Playing", color=0xf1c40f)                 
            embed.add_field(name="Title", value=f"**[{next_song.title}]({next_song.uri})**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Author", value=next_song.author, inline=False)                 
            embed.add_field(name="Duration | Seconds", value=next_song.length, inline=False)                 
            await channel.send(embed=embed)             
        elif do_not_have_next_song: #here also I do not know what should put in there                 
            await vc.disconnect()
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Nothing Left to Play", description=f"There is nothing left to play, left voice channel.", color=0xf1c40f)                 
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
````

Comment: I forget to add ``` ``` so make it look so ugly, now better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63658589/17067135 This may help you.

Comment: I try to use `vc.is_playing` but return False

Comment: If `vc.is_playing` is False, means your bot is not playing any music. Therefore you can let the bot left voice channel (disconnect) now.

Comment: After every song has finished, it will return False. I am petty sure there is song in queue.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

(This Source Code Will Check If The Queue Is Empty, If It Is And There Is No More Songs To Play, It Will Disconnect)
Try This:

```
import wavelink, discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed, Colour
from datetime import datetime



@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_track_end(player: wavelink.Player, track, reason):
    if not player.queue.is_empty:
        next_song = await player.queue.get_wait()
        await player.play(next_song)
    else:
        await player.disconnect()


@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx: commands.Context):
    try:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
        if not vc.queue.is_empty:
            await vc.stop()
        else:
            return await ctx.send("Queue Is Empty, What Now ¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
    except:
        embed = Embed(
            description='**Join A VC First!**',
            color=Colour.random(),
            timestamp=datetime.now()
        )
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```