# How to make bots leave voice channels when the music is not playing

Tags: python, discord.py

How to make discord bots leave voice channels when music is not playing.
I am making a music bot and I wanna make it auto-leave after 5 minutes when the music stops playing.

I have tried to use events, but anyway this is not working. Please guide me.

Comment: This question may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63658589/17067135

Answer (score 1):

Do this:
(I assume your using ctx, if you were to show your code I could help more if necessary) (I also add a little joke in my code, I apologize, I am a weird coder)

```
@client.command()
async def checkMusic(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await ctx.reply("I'm playin music! Don't bother me, I'm groovin!")
    else:
        await ctx.reply("Nothing is playing so I'm outta here!")
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
```

For your second question, @SorryForMyBadEnglish shows a great link for your question. (I looked at this myself when I was making my RickRoll bot) Have a wonderful day!