# Discord API Bot that enters and leaves discord voice channel automatically (without commands)

Tags: python, discord

I want to make a bot that automatically joins a voice channel when a member joins it and leaves it when there is no members in the voice channel. The problem I'm having is after it joins the voice channel, the disconnect function doesn't work. I've tried other disconnect functions from other posts and they didn't work either, or I didn't use them properly. This is a example of the code:

```
import discord
import random
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio




TOKEN="<redacted>"
client=discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  

  if not before.channel and after.channel and member.id == 450333776485285919 or member.id==232855365082021890 or member.id==282234566066962433 or member.id==256759154524291074:
      
    channel = client.get_channel(988050675604803648) 
   
    await channel.connect()
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    await channel.disconnect()
```

For this example I just made it so it joins and leaves after 3 seconds. I need help with what function I have to use to make it disconnect.

This is the error code I get:

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Tudos\Documents\mundo\.vscode\EldenBot.py", line 30, in on_voice_state_update
    await channel.disconnect()
AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'disconnect'
```

Comment: Im sorry if a similar question was asked before but i tryed disconnect examples from other threads and i couldnt implement them into my code sucesfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658589/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-leave-the-voice-channel-after-being-inactive-for-x-min